# Unrecognized pipeline stage name: ‘$unionWith’”

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I’m using "mongodb": "^4.4.1" version for NodeJS.
I'm trying to make the following query:

```js
db.collection('myCollection').aggregate([
  {
    $unionWith: {
      coll: "anotherCollection"
    }
  }
])
```

But i have the following error : `“Unrecognized pipeline stage name: ‘$unionWith’”`

Can you explain to me why am I getting this error?

I tried to explore the mongo signatures in `node_modules/mongodb/src/cursor/aggregation_cursor.ts` but there is no `unionWith` signatures.

Comment: What is the version of the MongoDB server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, i found the solution, it's my fault i made a mistake. It was working perfectly at node.js runtime, but the error was thrown during the jest unit tests. Because i forgot to update the mongodb memory server version for jest usage.

```
module.exports = {
  mongodbMemoryServerOptions: {
    binary: {
      version: '5.0.6',
      skipMD5: true,
    },
    autoStart: false,
    instance: {},
  },
};
```

It's working perfectly now.

Thank for your time and have a good day.